# Prism Xamarin.Forms using Repository + Logic Patterns + DI

Tags: prism

Good morning, I am developing a project in which I wish to use the following layers:

***Logical layer***: is responsible for performing the necessary validations between the data that you enter and the data that is obtained from the database (Repository).

***Repository layer***: only returns the data from the SQLite database. It has no validation logic.

How Prism uses DI (Dependency Injection) and IoC (Inversion of Control), to register the instances. I use the following code to instantiate the Logical Layer within the Portable project, which is quite good.

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
   base.ConfigureContainer();
   Container.RegisterInstance<IAccountLogic>(new AccountLogic());   
}
```

Inside the ViewModel Instanced in the constructor

```
public LoginViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService, IAccountLogic accountLogic = null)
{
   this.navigationService = navigationService;
   this.pageDialogService = pageDialogService;
   this.accountLogic = accountLogic;
}
```

My question is, how should I register my instance for the Repository Pattern? My repository is "***IUserAccountRepository***".

I want to implement this form since I want to have even more decoupled what is the logic and access to data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m91tr.png)

Finally, the "**IUserAccountRepository**" interface is located within the "**Domain**" project.

Any help will be very well received and thank you very much

Comment: La solución es muy simple.

En la Capa Logica, creo un constructor que recibe como parametro una instancia de mi repositorio. Como se muestra en el siguiente código.


Luego en el Container.RegisterInstance, le paso a la clase AccountLogic, una nueva intancia del repositorio que deseo acceder.

No estoy seguro si será la mejor manera de implementar la solución o no pero, para mi caso puntual me esta funcionando. Si hay una mejor solución me gustaría saberla.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple.

In the Logical Layer, I create a constructor that receives as an parameter an instance of my repository. As shown in the following code.

```
public AccountLogic(IUserAccountRepository userAccountRepository)
    {
        if (userAccountRepository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        _userAccountRepository = userAccountRepository;
    }
```

Then in the Container.RegisterInstance, I pass to the AccountLogic class, a new intance of the repository that I want to access.

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    Container.RegisterInstance<IAccountLogic>(new AccountLogic(new UserAccountRepository()));
}
```

I'm not sure if it will be the best way to implement the solution or not, but for my specific case it's working for me. If there is a better solution I would like to know it.